Unable to get scrollbar to appear on figure tag
I've been asked to sort of hack this preexisting template to essentially allow for scrolling within a div on an image that's too tall. This seems pretty straightforward, and, while it's been a long time since I've had to mess with scrollbars for any reason, I've done stuff like this before so I'm a little confused as to how/why it isn't working. I can only impact the containing div and the image inside it.
I've attempted the typical overflow settings (overflow-x: hidden, overflow-y: scroll) and they seem to be having no impact at all. My expectation is that the image will outsize the container and therefore trigger a scrollbar so the user can scroll down the image, but there must be some fundamental I'm not taking into account because so far it's just a nothing-burger. Code below:
HTML
<div id="image-1-container">
   <img class="image" id="main-image-1" src="some-image-path.png">  
</div>

CSS
#image-1-container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 25px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
}

#main-image-1 {
  height: 800px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

I'm not sure what the problem is here.
The image outsizes the container vertically, and a scrollbar appears as necessary. Maybe it's an issue with your browser or code editor.
I've just put it in a snippet below to demonstrate it does work.


#image-1-container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 25px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
}

#main-image-1 {
  height: 800px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div id="image-1-container">
   <img class="image" id="main-image-1" src="https://i0.wp.com/digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/1.-Moraine_final.jpg">  
</div>
</body>

</html>




Interesting, and quite bizarre. At least this confirms I'm not crazy and it should work. Must be something weird in the dev environment impacting this, I'll do some more digging. Thanks!
